# Evaluating a class of complex integrals

Tags: limits, complex-integration

I am given an expression like this:

$$\int_0^1 e^{-2\pi int} f(t) dt$$

How can I evaluate this, **just give me glance,like some line how to treat that `i`**,*I don't want actual solution.*

Comment: Do you have a particular $f$ in mind?

Comment: let assume x^2 or x^3 @Arthur

Answer (score 3):

This is a discrete Fourier transform. It's not something you solve in this general form (that can't really be done). You solve it separately for each and every $f$ you encounter. Some $f$s make it easy, some make it hard, and some make it impossible.

As for what to do with $i$, you treat it like any other constant, because that's what it is. It happens to be a constant such that $i^2 = -1$, and it happens to interact nicely with the exponential function, but at the end of the day, it's just a constant like any other.

Comment: It is not a Fourier transform. Fourier transform are from 0 to infinity, not 0 to 1.

Comment: @AbishekVangipuram $-\infty$ to $\infty$ actually. It's fixed now.